# Angle between to parametric vector

Tags: vectors

**Information given:**
$$r_{1} = (t,t^2,t^3)$$
$$r_{2} = (\sin t,\sin2t,t)$$ 
These vector intersect at origin $(0,0,0)$

**What I need to find:** The angle between them.

**What I tried:** I tried to use the formula $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{v_1\cdot v_2}{|v_1||v_2|}\right)$ , where $v_1 = r_1, v_2 =r_2$.
But when I calculate $v_1.v_2$ I obtain $(t\sin t+t^2\sin {2t} + t^4)$ where $t=0$ so the angle is always 0.

**The answer to this problem:** around 66$^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then the corresponding angle is the angle between two vectors which can be calculated using calculus$$v_1=r_1'=(1,2t,3t^2)\\v_2=r_2'=(\cos t,2\cos 2t,1)$$therefore $$v_1=(1,0,0)\\v_2=(1,2,1)\\\to\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{v_1\cdot v_2}{|v_1||v_2|}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 6}\right)$$

Comment: Why did you take the derivative?

Comment: Yea I would like to know too, because this is the good answer

Comment: Well! It is the tangent vector on its corresponding curve which is derived using $$\dfrac{r(x+\Delta x)-r(x)}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: Also use your intuition on 2D curves

Answer (score 0):

Let use

$$\cos \theta = \frac{r_1\cdot r_2}{|r_1||r_2|}\implies \theta = \arccos \frac{r_1\cdot r_2}{|r_1||r_2|}$$